# How to select only one row from duplicate date rows with condition

Tags: mysql

I have a result set which looks like as mentioned below, which I am getting from the query mentioned below:

```
LEAVE_DATE  | RESOURCE_ID | TYPE
2016-05-17 |    1         | SELF
2016-05-27 |    1         | SELF
2016-05-30 |    0         | ORG
2016-05-30 |    1         | SELF
```

Below is the SQL which gives me above result set:

```
SELECT CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8) LEAVE_DATE, v.RESOURCE_ID, v.TYPE
FROM date_tbl t,tbl_leave v
WHERE t.n <= DATEDIFF(v.END_DATE, v.START_DATE) + 1
AND RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0)
AND DAYOFWEEK(CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8)) NOT IN (1,7)
ORDER BY LEAVE_DATE
```

I want my SQL should return all the unique dates, but if duplicate date found with RESOURCE_ID 0 and 1, I would like to choose RESOURCE_ID 0.

expected result:

```
LEAVE_DATE  | RESOURCE_ID | TYPE
2016-05-17 |    1         | SELF
2016-05-27 |    1         | SELF
2016-05-30 |    0         | ORG
```

Could you please give some suggestion, how should I achieve this result?

Comment: Does type directly refer to resource_id? ie, is a resource_id of 1 always a type of 'self'?

Comment: type ORG alwalys be for resource_id =0
for SELF resource_id can be anything

Comment: You want record that resource_id = 0 when they have same date?

Comment: "*if duplicate date found with RESOURCE_ID 0 and 1, I would like to choose RESOURCE_ID 0*"—does that mean that duplicate dates with **equal** RESOURCE_ID should remain in the resultset?  What about where there is a date with, say, 3 records with RESOURCE_ID=0 and 2 records with RESOURCE_ID=1?  What should happen then?

Comment: What do you want returned when you have 2 rows for the same date both for resource_id of 1? In that case do you just want 1 returned or both?

Comment: @ Kickstart :  date can not be same for resource_id=1

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you do a select to get all your values and you order it by resource_id and the result you get you group it by leave_date.
The group by will get the first row on duplicate.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8) LEAVE_DATE, v.RESOURCE_ID, v.TYPE
FROM date_tbl t,tbl_leave v
WHERE t.n <= DATEDIFF(v.END_DATE, v.START_DATE) + 1
AND RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0)
AND DAYOFWEEK(CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8)) NOT IN (1,7)
ORDER BY v.RESOURCE_ID
)as x GROUP BY x.LEAVE_DATE
```

Comment: This will return a single resource_id and type for each date, but which one is returned is not defined. You could use MIN(resource_id) to make sure you got the 0 if one existed, but that doesn't help with the type. As type can have any value for a resource of 1 you cannot use MIN, MAX, or anything like that. You could possibly use an IF(resource_id = 0, 'ORG', type) AS type, but I am not keen on that.

Comment: The resurce_id what you will get its defined by ORDER BY v.RESOURCE_ID ASC | DESC if you have 2 results on this the x.GROUP BY will get only the first result.
And the type you will get it's the same that resource id you got from the order by and the group by.

Comment: No it isn't. Which non GROUP BY field that is not an aggregate field that is returned is not defined. MySQL could return any of them. This is an issue with MySQLs non standard handing of GROUP BY and how people misuse it.

Comment: More details are on the MySQL web site - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html .  _If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want._

Comment: @Kickstart and how about using also de  v.TYPE in the group by sentence?
Something like this


`SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8) LEAVE_DATE, v.RESOURCE_ID, v.TYPE
FROM date_tbl t,tbl_leave v
WHERE t.n <= DATEDIFF(v.END_DATE, v.START_DATE) + 1
AND RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0)
AND DAYOFWEEK(CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8)) NOT IN (1,7)
GROUP BY LEAVE_DATE,v.RESOURCE_ID,v.TYPE
ORDER BY LEAVE_DATE,v.RESOURCE_ID
)as x GROUP BY x.LEAVE_DATE`


I think this may give you the expected result.

Comment: Afraid not, as again it is just using GROUP BY x.LEAVE_DATE, and has no way to define which value of TYPE will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only ever want one record per date, then the only safe way I can see is to add a sequence number (ordered by leave_date then resource_id), and only return the first record for each date.

Not tested by something like this:-

```
SELECT LEAVE_DATE,
        RESOURCE_ID,
        TYPE
FROM
(
    SELECT LEAVE_DATE,
            RESOURCE_ID,
            TYPE,
            if(@prev_leave_date=LEAVE_DATE, @cnt + 1, 1) AS cnt,
            @prev_leave_date:=LEAVE_DATE
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8) LEAVE_DATE, 
                v.RESOURCE_ID, 
                v.TYPE
        FROM date_tbl t
        INNER JOIN tbl_leave v
        ON  t.n <= DATEDIFF(v.END_DATE, v.START_DATE) + 1
        WHERE RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0)
        AND DAYOFWEEK(CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8)) NOT IN (1,7)
        ORDER BY LEAVE_DATE, RESOURCE_ID
    ) sub0
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT @prev_leave_date:="", @cnt:=0
    ) sub1
) sub2
WHERE cnt = 1
```

Another option that avoids using sub queries is to abuse GROUP_CONCAT. Get each row, grouping by LEAVE_DATE and using GROUP_CONCAT on resource_id and type to get all the values for each one for each LEAVE DATE. Order both by resource_id so that ones with a resource_id of 0 come first. GROUP_CONCAT values are separated by a comma by default, so use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the first value from each of them (note that if either resource_id or type can contain a comma then you will need to specify a different delimiter and split the result by that).

Not tested (as no table declares or test data), but something like this:-

```
    SELECT CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8) LEAVE_DATE, 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(v.RESOURCE_ID ORDER BY v.RESOURCE_ID), ',', 1) AS RESOURCE_ID, 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(v.TYPE ORDER BY v.RESOURCE_ID), ',', 1) AS TYPE
    FROM date_tbl t
    INNER JOIN tbl_leave v
    ON  t.n <= DATEDIFF(v.END_DATE, v.START_DATE) + 1
    WHERE RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0)
    AND DAYOFWEEK(CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8)) NOT IN (1,7)
    GROUP BY LEAVE_DATE
    ORDER BY LEAVE_DATE, RESOURCE_ID
```

Comment: @pappukhode  Can you post your input table declares and a few lines of sample data so I can have a chance at debugging it

Comment: @pappukhode - added a possible different solution that doesn't use sub queries.

Comment: I am able to create a view for this one. but while executing I am getting below error:
Table 'v' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list

Comment: @pappukhode When do you get that error? If you just select everything from the view does it work?

Comment: view created successfully, but while executing its all fields its throwing error

Comment: @pappukhode I can see a typo where I have put an extra comma in (will fix that now), but nothing else. Can you post the table declares and a few lines of test data, and the SQL you are using to read from the view . Then I can test it.

Comment: extra comma was removed. only thing i did, I have removed  "WHERE RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0)" from the view, as resource id will be dynamic one. could be the issue, do you think so ?

Comment: @pappukhode No, that shouldn't be it. I have just tried it with a guess at your table declares and data and it created a view and got the data from the view without an error. Can do it on SQLfiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8056/1 . And removing the _WHERE RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0)_ http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bde2bd also works. I really do need the table declares and test data to give any useful help beyond this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112987/discussion-between-pappu-khode-and-kickstart).

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly answer, but as your description from question and comment, this may be a simple answer.

```
SELECT LEAVE_DATE, IF(COUNT(1) > 1, 0, RESOURCE_ID) AS RESOURCE_ID, IF(COUNT(1) > 1, 'ORG', `TYPE`) AS `TYPE`
FROM(
    SELECT CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8) LEAVE_DATE, v.RESOURCE_ID, v.`TYPE`
    FROM date_tbl t,tbl_leave v
    WHERE t.n <= DATEDIFF(v.END_DATE, v.START_DATE) + 1
    AND RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0)
    AND DAYOFWEEK(CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8)) NOT IN (1,7)
    ORDER BY LEAVE_DATE)
GROUP BY LEAVE_DATE
```

**Edited:**

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8) LEAVE_DATE,
    IF(COUNT(1) > 1, 0,v.RESOURCE_ID) AS RESOURCE_ID,
    IF(COUNT(1) > 1, 'ORG', v.`TYPE`) AS `TYPE`
FROM date_tbl t,tbl_leave v
WHERE t.n <= DATEDIFF(v.END_DATE, v.START_DATE) + 1
-- AND RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0) -- This is what you want to remove!!!
AND DAYOFWEEK(CONVERT(v.START_DATE + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY USING utf8)) NOT IN (1,7)
ORDER BY LEAVE_DATE
GROUP BY LEAVE_DATE
```

Comment: By the way, are there also same date records exsit when resource_id =1? If yes, this will not work.

Comment: could you please tell me how can I accommodate this answer into view. as view doesn't allow for subquery. Also I want to move out "RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0)" this part outside as id passed will be dynamic

Comment: @pappukhode If you remove `RESOURCE_ID IN (1,0)` from where clause, is the result also like that in question?

Comment: @pappukhode If yes, please check my answer if it works for you or not. If not, ignore my edited answer.